# i am getting Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am getting msg 512 in SQL. what i am trying is to display employee name from I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER.

```
SELECT  A.MONTH,(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA 
WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR AND 
PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN 
(SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL 
WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'P') AND 
PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND PD_CODE = 'Z500') AS GROSS_PERMANENT,
(SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER),
(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE 
AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR AND PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN
(SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE 
AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'F') AND PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN  1 AND 10 AND PD_CODE = 'Z500') 
AS GROSS_CASUAL  FROM I_HR_SYS_DATE_MONTHLY A WHERE A.EMPLOYER_CODE = 'RAD' AND 
A.TAX_YEAR = 2014
```

Comment: Simple answer: Learn [**SQL Joins**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: "Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1" is product specific error message, but which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please post your table formats.

Comment: im using here multiple tables and view @Patrick  . which table format you are asking about?

Comment: All to get this code working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
     SELECT  A.MONTH,(  SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) 
                    FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA 
                    WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR AND 
                            PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN 
                                (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID 
                                 FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL 
                                WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'P') AND 
                                    PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND PD_CODE = 'Z500') AS GROSS_PERMANENT,
                                 b.EMPLOYEE_NAME    as employeename,                                
                                (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE 
                            AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR AND PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN
                            (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE 
                                    AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'F') AND PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN  1 AND 10 AND PD_CODE = 'Z500') 
                                        AS GROSS_CASUAL  
FROM I_HR_SYS_DATE_MONTHLY A 
JOIN I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER b on b.EMPLOYER_CODE=A.EMPLOYER_CODE
```

WHERE A.EMPLOYER_CODE = 'RAD' AND A.TAX_YEAR = 2014

Comment: i am still getting this error. Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: now check but I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER table contain multiple entry of employer_code

Comment: Mukesh now im getting result but all entries are getting first employeename. yes, one employer_code has multiple employee_ids

Comment: how can i get all employee_name which having the same employer_code.

Comment: @Kirat if you are use mssql then use GROUP_CONCAT now check it

Comment: I am using SQL server @Mukesh..with this code im getting these errors...:( Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Mukesh ..it gave me all names but in one row. e.g. i have 10 different employee_ids and each id getting all employee_names in single row..

Comment: help me out from this please.

Comment: @kirat now check this query but all columns are repeted

Comment: thank you for your effort but with this query im getting different employee's name but now im getting same value of  rest of the columns like GROSS CASUAL, MONTH, and GROSS_PAYMENT..:( Please help Mukesh.

Comment: @Kirat i tried to resolve your bug. not say tanks if help out then given vote and right marks.

Comment: this result effected my other data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have column employee id in your main table so that you can join it with employee master.

**But I really doubt what you will achieve from this query. **

```
SELECT  A.MONTH,
(

  SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR AND 
  PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'P') AND 
  PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND PD_CODE = 'Z500'
) AS GROSS_PERMANENT,
--(SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER),
B.EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
(
  SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE 
  AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR AND PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN
  (SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE 
  AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'F') AND PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN  1 AND 10 AND PD_CODE = 'Z500'
) AS GROSS_CASUAL  
FROM I_HR_SYS_DATE_MONTHLY A 
left outer join I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER B on A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE A.EMPLOYER_CODE = 'RAD' AND A.TAX_YEAR = 2014
```

Comment: im getting these errors with this query.although i have column in employee_master. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'EMPLOYEE_ID'.